# Resource ID of Button Defined Using Include Directive in Layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I came across an app, whose layout puzzles me.

Assume two layout XML files, such that one includes the other:

activity_button.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/button"/>

</LinearLayout>%
```

button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/button" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage">    
</Button>
```

What is the resource ID of the button?

I thought one always had to specify ID via `android:id` attribute, so I am confused why this layout works. I also checked the `R.java` ID entry and it seems to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android:id

Is not mandatory field for a view in the layout xml file. the only two mandatory fields are the width and height of the view.

Think of situations when you want a layout to simply show some title without any business need to change it through the activity life time. for this need you don't need to obtain this view id, and don't need the overhead of creating id for this view

Answer (score 1):

> What is the resource ID of the button?

Doesn't have one

> I thought one always had to specify ID via `android:id` attribute

Why did you think this? You often leave off this attribute for the root views of most layouts. (See `LinearLayout` of your question)

You do not need an `android:id` if you never expect to find the view using an ID. Since the onClick is defined in the XML, there's really no purpose in finding the button.